# webpack 2, angular 2 - using "require" with path built using variable

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, require, webpack-2

my issue is this:
whenever I'm using the following syntax inside angular ->

```
let myCmp = 'test1';

let cmp = require('./components/'+myCmp+'/bootstrapCmp.component.ts');
```

I'm getting all the components that inside the components folder within my final bundle, not just 'test1';

(I'm using the angular 2 WebPack starter pack of the AngularClass team -
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter

Had anyone this issue too?

the component I'm loading / so is all other ones are basic angular 2 components.

thanks in advance, I'm struggling with it for too much ^^

Comment: Think about general case. How would bundler know in advance which components to include in bundle w/o running the code?

Comment: You could also read this [discussion](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1421).

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thanks for quick response! the only answer i can think of when you put it like this is by using the webpack config files..is there any way to require the relevant files in the webpack's config file and access them in the angular's app ? and why the bunlder can't read the variable's value while using it in a the require's path ?

Answer (score 0):

hope the solution i found for myself will help other developers :

in the webpack.common.js file i've added new file to my entry object which i called : boot.js .

so the structure is like this :

```
entry: {
  main:['./src/polyfills.browser.ts','./src/assets/boot.ts','./src/main.browser.ts']
}
```

the boot.ts file, contains an object with all the relavent components that i will be using (references).

while the bunlder (wepback) is running, whenever i need some component i'm going to this object i've created inside the boot.ts file, the final bundle file contains now only the components i want.